# Applying order to OpenEntityManagerInView possible?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, servlet-filters

I am using OpenEntityManagerInView in my application, so that EntityManager is open and closed automatically as per the request lifecycle. Also, I have one filter in my application that is responsible for providing authentication via interacting with DB.

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    IAuthService service;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException {
        /*doing auth stuff here: 
         *service.validateUser(payload);
         *responsible for opening and closing em
        */
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
    }
}
```

Since this filter is talking with DB, it's opening EntityManager during its operation and closing after it is done(automatically due to `@Transactional` annotation).

After successful authentication, it's calling other filters if any in the chain.

The challenge which I am facing is **OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor is called after the above filter is done with its authentication**, which in turn is leading to the session being open and closed two times per request, first on auth filter and second on OpenEntityManagerInView

**How can I make OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor being called before all the filters specified in the application**, so that filter can use already open EntityManager for DB operations(if req)

Tried `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` above filter, but didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You can only configure the order of servlet filters through a web.xml

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561816/412446

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `HandlerInterceptor` instead of a servlet filter and set it's order to be after the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76210504/98632